# Explaining flatMap associativity

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am reading `Functional Programming in Scala` and the book comments that flatMap for monads must follow the associativity law as per below.

`x.flatMap(f).flatMap(g) == x.flatMap(a => f(a).flatMap(g))`

I normally take associativity to mean something like `(a+(b+c))` == `((a+b)+c)` but I am failing to translate the equation here to something similar.

The two sides seem equivalent to me. Assuming x is of type `M[A]`, They both seem to be applying `f` first to `a` and subsequently applying `flatMap(g)` to the result of `f(a)`.

What is the significance of this law?

Comment: On the LHS `f` has been applied to all elements of `x` before the first application of `g`. On the RHS the application of `f` is followed by the application of `g` before the next element of `x` is processed. That's how I read it, even though it's hard to imagine how any `flatMap()` could fail this test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're confused by the syntax and have trouble seeing analogy to `(a+(b+c))==((a+b)+c)`, consider composing functions of type `A => M[B]` where `A` and `B` can change while `M` stays the same. Now consider an operation which composes these functions like that:

```
def compose[A,B,C](f: A => M[B], g: B => M[C]): A => M[C] =
  a => f(a).flatMap(g)
```

Now the associativity law reads like:

```
compose(compose(f, g), h) == compose(f, compose(g, h))
```

If we had some infix operator for `compose`, it could look like this:

```
(f comp g) comp h == f comp (g comp h)
```

BTW: In functional programming terminology, these functions are called [Kleisli](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/kleisli.html)

Comment: Ah thanks! Okay, this makes sense to me when the elements being composed are of type `A => M[B]`. 

I'm not quite sure how it works in the original example though `x.flatMap(f).flatMap(g)`, this would mean `x` is of type `A=>M[A]` as well?